# DISPLAY MIN() and MAX() Values in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have a table called **cia** with 2 columns:

Column 1 (**'Name'**) has the names of all countries in the world. 
Column 2 (**'area'**)has the size of those countries in m^2.

I want to find the biggest and smallest country. To find those I need to enter the following Queries:

```
SELECT Name, MAX(area) FROM cia
```

My other query:

```
SELECT Name, MIN(area) FROM cia
```

Now obviously I could do

```
SELECT MIN(area), MAX(area) FROM cia
```

however, I wouldn't get the corresponding name to my values then. Is it possible to get an output like this

**Country     | Fläche**

Afghanistan | lowest value of column 'area'

China        | highest value of column 'area'

Comment: Rename table "cia" to countries, rename column "name" to country! (Name is a too generic name to be a name...)

Comment: For sure. Thing is, it's not my database. It's just there for learning SQL.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the minimum size:

```
select min(area) from cia;
```

And this the maximum:

```
select max(area) from cia;
```

So:

```
select * from cia 
where area = (select min(area) from cia)
   or area = (select max(area) from cia)
order by area;
```

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
Sorry, my first thought was wrong. But this works.

```
SELECT Typ = 'MaxValue', * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Name, area FROM cia ORDER BY area DESC) tmp1
UNION ALL 
SELECT Typ = 'MinValue', * FROM (SELECT TOP 1 Name, area FROM cia ORDER BY area ASC) tmp2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query:

```
CREATE TABLE area (name varchar(50), area int);

insert into area values ('Italy', 1000);
insert into area values ('China', 10000);
insert into area values ('San Marino', 10);
insert into area values ('Ghana', 3333);

select main.* from area main
where 
not exists(
  SELECT 'MINIMUM'
  FROM area a2
  where a2.area < main.area
  )
or
not exists(
  SELECT 'MAXIMUM'
  FROM area a3
  WHERE a3.area > main.area
  )
```

order by area desc

In this way write only two subqueries. Other ways can go in error with other DBMS (no use of GROUP BY to show Name)

Go to [Sql Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d0705/1/0)

Answer (score 1):

You obviously have to hit the table twice, but there is no need for three hits.

```
select  case Area when MaxArea then 'Largest' else 'Smallest' end Rating, b.Name as Country, b.Area
from(
    select  Max( Area ) as MaxArea, Min( Area ) as MinArea
    from    Cia a
) S
join    Cia b
    on  b.Area = s.MaxArea
    or  b.Area = s.MinArea;
```